# How Do I get GUID from a DLL generated on VisualBasic 6 using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, dll, vb6, guid

I got a DLL compiled on VB6, I need to automatize some steps to make developers life easier, one of them is to get DLL's GUID right after is compiled, but I got no clue how to do it.

I appreciate your time, thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know about PowerlessShell but it shouldn't take much of a VBScript or command line VB6 program using the Typelib Information (TLI) library to obtain this information.

Comment: Why are you doing this? It seems to me that you want [Binary Compatibility](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/demystifying-version-compatibility-settings-in-visual-basic/).

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't take much of a VBScript, but my knowledge in Visua Basic is close to none. Maybe you could point me in the right direction.
I'm doing this to automatize some steps of the production. Thank you for your answers

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://highspeedlowdrag.wordpress.com/2017/04/13/powershell-extract-tlbid-progid-clsid-from-com-dll/) helps?

Comment: Add-Type -Path 'C:\Path\to\MyVB.dll' ;

[MyNameSpace.MyClass] | Get-Member ; 
#  This shows GUID as a property.  BUT -- I have not been able to get a value in my testing.    
$MyObj = New-Object MyNameSpace.MyClass ;
$MyObj.GUID   # Returned nothing for me.